# Externalizing a very large tikz file

Tags: tikz-external

I am having trouble and some confusing behaviour while trying to produce a large tikz picture. Here is the minimal example of the problem. I should note that I am doing all the work online on Overleaf.

This is my main file main.tex:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
    
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} % line X
    \input{pic}
\end{tikzpicture} % line Y
\end{document}
```

The file pic.tex is very large (complete file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4y55722kolntx66tpa333/pic.tex?rlkey=avtou7z44l7odmph8j5jph5yf&dl=0)), but basically it looks like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [scale=4]

    % 10000 lines, each drawing one short segment in a different color
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The following two strange things happen:

1. I get the following result

[image]

but I am 100% certain the result should be

[image]

For some reason the two thirds of the picture are trimmed.

2. Note that I actually have two nested tikzpicture environments. For some reason this doesn't throw an error, but if I try to remove one of them by commenting line X and line Y in main.tex, I get the error

   ```
   TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
   ```

This doesn't make any sense to me, why does having two nested tikzpicture environments help here? Is there a more logical way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried with a shorter pic? Result?

Comment: If you remove the `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]` and `\end{tikzpicture}` from pic.tex and add `[scale=4]` in the main file, everything seems to work. I don't know the internals of TikZ well enough to understand why.

Comment: @Mensch Yes, with a shorter picture it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Senex Hmmm, that's really strange... I'd really like to know what is going on here.